# Using vim along with screen

Tags: bash, vim, gnu-screen

When I'm using vim alone, it's fine. I can suspend it by pressing **Ctrl+z**, work with bash, then return by typing **fg**.

When I'm trying to use vim along with gnu-screen, it's buggy.

First, pressing  Ctrl+z does not show me all previous commands in console, it shows remains of vim screen instead(see pic).

Second, and worse, hotkeys, starting with **Ctrl** does not work in Vim. For example, **Ctrl+PgUp** to see previous tab.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are already using screen why not just split the window to use the terminal? If you are using vim 8.1 and above just use `:term` to start a new terminal inside the vim. If you want to run a single command you can use `:! command`, where command is the terminal command you want to run.

Comment: Great, but what about hotkeys, started with  Ctrl in vim? It's blocked by screen, which makes vim completely unusable. Same with tmux.

Comment: @rtka can yoy explain, what means setting term=xterm?

Comment: I'm having similar problems, with some key combinations mapped in my .vimrc which work correctly out of a GNU screen session, but do not work correctly within a screen session.
C-Tab, C-j, S-C-j, C-k, S-C-k do not behave in a consistent manner. I'm trying to understand things like terminfo and infocmp.
But on my side, Ctrl-Z works correctly.